# Loop through entries that share current entry category and restrict to Cat Group Id

Tags: entries, categories, relations

I've been racking my brains trying to get my head around categories and entries, hopefully someone can help and show me the best way.

I have an entry page with product information and this product is assigned to multiple categories across multiple groups. I need to exclude the category 'preferential' and only show entries that belong to the category group 'offers'.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo(entry) %}    
{% set excludeCat = craft.categories.slug('preferential').first() %}

{% set allIds = [] %}
{% for id in categories.ids() if id != excludeCat.id %}
    {% set allIds = allIds|merge([id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(allIds) %}

{% for offer in entries %}                    
    <a href="{{ offer.url }}">{{ offer.title }}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried variations of 'group', 'ids' and 'groupId' but no joy. This is my first Craft CMS build so still learning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of 'not' to exclude items from your parameters. An example of how this would be implemented in the above use case would be as follows

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.slug( 'not preferential' ) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo( categories ) %}
```

If you need to specify category groups or entry sections then use

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group( 'groupHandle' ).slug( 'not preferential' ) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section( 'sectionHandle' ).relatedTo( categories ) %}
```